# Is there any way to make MySql database "update itself"?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysql, database

I have a mysql database, or more specific, a mysql table which I store IP adresses in.

This is because I limit the nr of messages being sent from my website.
I simply check if the IP is in the table, and if it is, I tell the user to "slow down".

Is there any way to make this MySql table only store a row (a record) for `x` minutes?

Other solutions are also appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use a [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) field to store when the row was inserted / modified and occasionally delete rows that are older than x minutes.

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE your_timestamp < NOW() - interval 5 minute
```

To solve your actual problem though, I'd suggest having a table with a row for each user and the last time they sent a message. Assuming it is indexed correctly and your queries are efficient you probably won't ever need to delete any rows from this table, except perhaps if you use a foreign key to the user table and delete the corresponding user. When a user sends a message insert a row if it already exists, otherwise update the existing row (you can use for example the MySQL extension REPLACE for this if you wish).

Comment: Do I write exactly as you write it, "NOW() - interval 5 minute" to get a 5 minute interval? If not, care to update with how I should write the code to compare the timestamp to be between now() and say 3 hours on?

Comment: @Camran: That gives you the time 5 minutes ago. Try running `SELECT NOW() - interval 3 hour` and you should get the time 3 hours ago.

Comment: I actually have a DATETIME field, and the interval doesn't work. Is there anyway of using something like 3*60*60 for three hours?

Comment: @amran: Subtracting an interval also works for DATETIME columns. One error you may have made is to type `hours` instead of `hour`. The unit *must* be in singular form in MySQL. If you still can't get it working, please post the exact query you tried, together with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you add a WHERE clause concerning time to the SELECT "simply check if the IP is in the table"

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = <whatever> and timestamp > NOW() - 3*60
```

Then maybe empty out that table once every night.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a column that has the timestamp of the last sent message and another that has the total number of posts. Before updating the table check if at least X minutes has passed since the last post. If so, change the total number of posts to 1, otherwise increment the value by 1.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that doesn't involve *deleting* the IP addresses after a certain interval is to store the addresses as "temporal" data, i.e. records that are only valid for a certain period.

Simplest way to do that would be to add a timestamp column to the table and, when entering an IP, capture either the time it was entered into the table, or the time after which it is no longer being "limited".

The code that grabs IPs to be limited then checks the timestamp to see if it's either:

- **older than a certain threshold** (e.g. if you recorded the IP more than an hour ago, ignore it) or
- **the current time is greater than the expiry date stored there** (e.g. if an IP's timestamp says 2010-11-23 23:59:59 and that is in the past, ignore it)

depending on what you choose the timestamp to represent.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here using a timestamp and a cron job are probably your best option, but if you insist on mysql handling this itself, you could use [Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html). They're like cron jobs, except mysql handles the scheduling itself. It requires 5.1+ though.